# Push default settings to clients from print management

Tags: windows, configuration-management, print-server

We have installed 30 printers to some 500 clients in our company using print management in Windows 2012 Server. Now we changed the default settings to the printers in print management (changed from default color to b&w).

How can i push these settings to the clients? If i reinstall the printers, the settings Will apply, but we want to avoid reinstalling in 500 clients.

Comment: How about just using GPOs to push settings?

Comment: How exactly would i push the setting via GPO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the funcionality exists within the Windows Print Management, it was a bug of Windows Server 2012 that didnt push the changes. More information: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3201130/printing-preferences-from-the-print-server-don-t-synchronize-in-window

For those having this problem, you need to keep in mind, that once the user changes the settings a local profile Will be created and the server wont push the settings anymore (tested in Windows Server 2012).

Answer (score 0):

If you make a shared printer, the default settings are saved on the server and the users default settings are lost. User GPO or login scripts to remove all the printers and readd them where you changed the settings.

printscript.vbs script example:

**Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

WshNetwork.RemovePrinterConnection "\Server\ricoh" 
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\Server\ricohBW"**